# differential equation of complex variable.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve the differential equation with two complex variables.
$$ \frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial w_1^2} = -z  \;,\; \frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial w_2^2} = -z$$
$$ \frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial w_1\partial w_2} = \frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial w_2\partial w_1}=0$$
where $z(w_1, w_2) , w_1, w_2$ are complex variables.

I tried to use the case of solving equation $y=y(x) $ with $y'' +y =0 $, but I have no idea for multi-variable case.

How should I solve this?

Comment: Seems like $z=0$ is the only solution here. You have too many equations.

Answer (score 1):

Try starting with your bottom two equations.

(this is assuming that $z, w_1, w_2$ are all complex)

Letting $\frac{\partial z}{\partial w_1} = F(z)$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial w_2} = G(z)$, then you should note that $\frac{\partial z}{\partial w_1 \partial w_2} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial w_2} = 0 =\frac{\partial G}{\partial w_1} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial w_2 \partial w_1}$.

Therefore, $F(z)$ and $G(z)$ must be constants.

Letting some $z_o$ stand for your constant, you can then plug into the upper two equations. Note that the only constant for which your second partial derivative is $-z$, is $0$.